# Multiple replace regex in one Apache-NiFi statement

Tags: regex, csv, apache-nifi

I have a csv in following format.

```
id,mobile
1,02146477474
2,08585377474
3,07646474637
4,02158789566
5,04578599525
```

I want to add a new column and add just leading 3 numbers to that column (for specific cases and all the others `NOT_VALID` string). So result should be:

```
id,number,provider
1,02146477474,021
2,08585377474,085
3,07646474637,NOT_VALID
4,02158789566,021
5,04578599525,NOT_VALID
```

I can use following regex for replacing that. But I would like to use all possible conversations in one step. Using `UpdateRecord` processor.

```
${field.value:replaceFirst('085[0-9]+','085')}
```

When I use something like this:

```
${field.value:replaceFirst('085[0-9]+','085'):or(${field.value:replaceFirst('086[0-9]+','086')}`)}
```

This replaces all with `false`.

Comment: Look for captures etc in the regexes.  You might need to use `([0-9]{3})` to capture three digits (or, more long-windedly, `([0-9][0-9][0-9])`), and then perhaps `$1` or `\1` in the replacement.  Or it might be completely different — I've not studied Apache-NiFi and its regexes at all.  But the key to doing it sanely will be to use regexes that recognize three digits at the start of field 2 and make them into the whole of new field 3.  Have fun with the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Nifi uses Java regex

As soon, as you are using record processing, this should work for you:

```
${field.value:replaceFirst('^(021|085)?.*','$1')}
```

The group `()` optionally `?` catches `021` or `085` at the beginning of string `^`

The replacement - `$1` - is the first group

---

PS: The sites like https://regex101.com/ helps to understand regex

Comment: result is just `"${field.value:replaceFirst('((,\\d{3}).*)', '$1$2')"` on my last column.

Comment: I can replace one value using `${field.value:replaceFirst('085[0-9]+','085')}`, but what I want is, do all transformations in one step.

Comment: I have tried many times. But this wont solve the issue. Because I need to check for two options else put some other string.

Comment: There is one option in your question. Take first 3 digits. What is another one?

Comment: I have tried combining two expressions. but using `or` , its not solving the issue. 
here if its `085***` then only `085`, if `021***` then `021` and all others its `none`

Comment: modified the answer

Comment: @Sachith: why does your example input and output show `076` being modified if only `085` and `021` are supposed to be handled?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, that was my mistake, I have updated the question now.